# Averaging objects within collection and treating like a new object within same collection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a collection of custom objects which are mirrored in the UI

Interface (extremely simplified)

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  int Data { get; set; }
}
```

Collection

```
MyCollection<IMyInterface> Foo;
```

UI (which displays contents of `Foo` in a sensible way, e.g.)

```
Name: [ asdf ] Data: [ 1234 ]
Name: [ qwer ] Data: [ 5678 ]
Name: [ zxcv ] Data: [ 0000 ]
```

I now have the need in my program to be able to open two `IMyInterface` types and display the average data, along with single `IMyInterface` objects:

```
Name: [ asdf ] Data: [ 1234 ]
Name: [ qwer ] Data: [ 5678 ]
Name: [ zxcv ] Data: [ 0000 ]
Name: [ 2 Objects (asdf, qwer) ] Data: [ 3456 ]
```

I must be able to get out `asdf` and `qwer` from this new average.

What is the best way I can achieve this? I feel I have three options:

1. Make a type which inherits from `IMyInterface` with an internal
   collection of `IMyInterface`s. However, this feels a bit dirty as
   some of the properties are not averageable.
2. Replace `Foo` with `MyCollection> and where ever I use it, make a check to the count of the inner collection
3. Turn MyCollection into a dictionary-like object where I can specify a "group" for each object then I can get out objects by their group ID.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What determines which items are averaged?  You omitted `zxcv` in your example.

Comment: winforms? wpf? asp? what UI technology are you using?

Comment: @zxcv It would be user choice to determine which items are averaged (in my actual application this is done by ListView - a user may activate a single item or select multiple items to be activated).

Comment: @MattDavey The UI isn't really as important as the underlying collection in this case, but it is WinForms.

Comment: @dav_i I think it's quite vital to point out what UI technology you're using, as something like WPF would have opened up a lot more options on how to tackle something like this.

Comment: @MattDavey Just showing my ignorance then I guess! :)

Comment: so you have a list of IMyInterface, a user can select any ammount he wants, and you need to create another IMyinterface with the names of the objects and their average?

Comment: @YavgenyP That would be my option #1 in this case.

Comment: @dav_i, yeah but the question is what is the purpose, and this should lead you to design. this optoin, btw, is perfectly "legal" - this is how the [composition pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) works

Comment: @YavgenyP Is this similar to how Exception has InnerException?

Comment: @dav_i yeah, but the more appropriate sample i guess is the way control trees work in .net (be that win forms or web). each control has also an array of Controls, which allw you to access its child controls. All in all, you get a tree of ur class instances, while its up to you what do with the irellevant properties (like return null or anything like that)

Comment: @YavgenyP Ah okay. Put that in the form of an answer and I'll happily accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), a good sample of which is the controls tree in .net:

Each IMyInterace can have a collection of IMyInterfaces, and its your choice what to do with the irrelevant properties (you can always return a null)